# Multiple .replace() on same selector seems to be conflicting

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'm planning on changing the color of key words in my text, and using multiple .replace()
 calls on the same element.

```
var $hotPinkList = [
"html",
"head",
"title",
"body",];

for (i = 0; i < $hotPinkList.length; i++) {
    $("code").html(function (_, html) {
        var rep = $hotPinkList[i];
        var regex = new RegExp(rep, 'g');
        return html.replace(regex, '<span style="color:#f92772;">' + $hotPinkList[i] + '</span>');
    });
}
```

and

```
$('code').html($('code').html().replace(/3noClr/g, '').replace(/".*?"/g, '<span style="color:red;">$&</span>'));
```

seem to be conflicting in a strange way. The style="color:#f92772;" is being added to the string and not taken as a html command when they are combined

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/D2vQ6/

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/vQdg7/

but
This doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/uE8qa/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression `/".*?"/` is matching the quotes in `<span style="color:#f92772;">` that were created in the `for` loop, so that replacement is turning that into `<span style=<span style="color:red;">"color:#f92772;"</span>>`. This isn't valid HTML.

You presumably need to restrict your replacement to text nodes, not HTML tags.

Comment: thanks that was exactly it, I just switched the order of the functions and it works great, thank you for your insight!